# Name a game that teaches elementary school kids

Tags: recommendations, teaching

I am a Media Specialist in an elementary school. I have created a small gaming library for my afterschool kids - but I would like to expand it to classroom use.

I need games that are under 30 minutes and teach the curriculum of Kinder to 6th graders. That is pretty wide open in scale...but that's my job.

I have the Timeline series, and adventures in Addiplication. These are the sorts of games I am looking for. Fun is my number one priority...but curriculum is the teacher's focus.

Comment: Cribbage is great for addition and multiplication. It can be played to 61 points instead of 121 points to make a shorter game.

Comment: I am choosing not to expand this to be a full answer due to the length of my answer. Damath seems to be useful

Comment: This question will get nice, long answers on BGG:  https://boardgamegeek.com/